# Modal Not Showing Up on laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, twitter-bootstrap

I've been making a crud application in laravel. The application was working fine until I decided to change some code. The modal was showing up when I was running the code earlier and when I tested a few hours ago it was just working fine. But now when I try to click on the add button, the url just changes and nothing shows up anymore. If anyone can help me I'll appreciate it. I've just been learning laravel for a few months now. Here's my code.

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')

 <div class="container">
<div class="row p-3">
    <div class="col-md-11 card p-3">
        <h5 class="text-center text-primary">Products</h5>
        <div class="form-group">
            
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                  <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-body">
                        ...
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  
</div>
@endsection
```

I just want the modal to pop up when I click on the button. Even though nothing shows up on the modal as for now. The js and cdn links are included in my file.

Comment: `Right click` -> `Click inspect` -> `Select console`

Comment: I tried that before posting the question. The console doesn't display any errors or warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `bs` from `data-bs-toggle` & `data-bs-target`

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</a>
```